# Firedac with Interbase some forms only updates database after closing appalication

Tags: delphi, transactions, firedac, interbase

I'm using firedac with Delphi 10.3 with Interbase, when i use an update SQL statement in more forms it will work perfect.

But in one form i do exact the same the table is not updated, but when i close the form and close the application the update is done to the database.

I'm completely lost and i don't know how this is possible.

I found a part of the problem:

When i use Commit it works, but when there is a open command between two update statements i need to use StartTransAction before the open en Commit after the open. Then the second update works:

```
DM_IB.IBF_VHE.ExecSQL('Update BB_ASML_FORECAST set Uren_Montage = 100, Uren_Berekend = ''Ja'' ' +
                        'where AANMAAK_DATUMTIJD = ''19-10-2022 10:12:38'' and ItemCode = ''4022.472.18632'' ') ;

    DM_IB.IBF_VHE.Commit ;

    ShowMessage('1') ; // Works no problems

  MEM_VPA.DisableControls ;
  MEM_Fouten.DisableControls ;

  Post_Confirm := False ;

  Try
    MEM_VPA.Close ;
    MEM_VPA.Open ;
    MEM_VPA.EmptyTable ;

    MEM_Fouten.Close ;
    MEM_Fouten.Open ;
    MEM_Fouten.EmptyTable ;

    With TFDQuery.Create(nil) do
    Try
      Connection := DM_IB.IBF_VHE ;
      SQL.Text   := 'select * from PL_CAPACITEIT_NPW where ' +
                    '(jaar = ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy', now()) + ' and ' +
                    'Weeknummer > ' + IntToStr(WeekofTheyear(Now())) + ') or ' +
                    '(jaar = ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy', IncYear(Now())) + ' and ' +
                    'weeknummer < ' + IntToStr(52 - (52 - WeekofTheyear(Now()))) + ') order by jaar, weeknummer' ;
    DM_IB.IBF_VHE.StartTransaction ; // when this line is nod add and the commit the update below is not working till i end the application
    Open ;
    DM_IB.IBF_VHE.Commit ;

    DM_IB.IBF_VHE.StartTransaction ;

    DM_IB.IBF_VHE.ExecSQL('Update BB_ASML_FORECAST set Uren_Montage = 100, Uren_Berekend = ''Ja'' ' +
                        'where AANMAAK_DATUMTIJD = ''19-10-2022 10:12:38'' and ItemCode = ''4022.472.88135'' ') ;

    DM_IB.IBF_VHE.Commit ;

    ShowMessage('2') ; // Works only when de above open command is between a transacion.
```

Thanks in advice,

Comment: It's kind of hard to help when we don't see the code.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello,

The problem is that the updates are commited to interbase only when i close the complete application.

I use a StartTransaction -> Update statement -> CommitRetaining but the data is not stored in de database.

When i close the complete application only then the changes are visible.